# how handel method dispatch on null self argument is disallowed?

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MSA_SCHEMA.PKG_ORDER AS
    PROCEDURE PROCESS_JSON_DATA(P_JSON_DATA IN VARCHAR2) IS
        V_RRN VARCHAR2(50);
        V_STAN VARCHAR2(50);
        V_NATIONAL_CODE VARCHAR2(100);
        V_CARD_NUMBER VARCHAR2(50);
        V_TERMINAL_NUMBER VARCHAR2(50);
        V_CHANNEL_TYPE NUMBER;
        V_REQUEST_DATE DATE;
        V_AMOUNT NUMBER;
        V_COMMODITY_CODE VARCHAR2(50);
        V_QUANTITY NUMBER;
        V_UNIT_CODE VARCHAR2(10);
        V_ORDER_ID NUMBER;
        json_data json_object_t;
        order_items json_array_t;
        order_item json_object_t;
    BEGIN
        IF P_JSON_DATA IS NOT NULL THEN
            json_data := json_object_t(P_JSON_DATA);
            
            IF json_data IS NOT NULL THEN
                V_RRN := json_data.get_string('rrn');
                V_STAN := json_data.get_string('stan');
                V_NATIONAL_CODE := json_data.get_string('nationalCode');
                V_CARD_NUMBER := json_data.get_string('cardNumber');
                V_TERMINAL_NUMBER := json_data.get_string('terminalNumber');
                V_CHANNEL_TYPE := json_data.get_number('channelType');
                V_REQUEST_DATE := TO_DATE(json_data.get_number('requestDate'), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS');
                V_AMOUNT := json_data.get_number('amount');
                order_items := json_data.get_array('orderItems');

                -- Assuming ITEMORDER_SEQ is a sequence
                V_ORDER_ID := MSA_SCHEMA.ITEMORDER_SEQ.NEXTVAL;

                -- Process order items
                FOR i IN 0..order_items.get_size() LOOP
                    order_item := json_object_t(order_items.get(i)); -- Corrected assignment
                    IF order_item IS NOT NULL THEN
                        V_COMMODITY_CODE := order_item.get_string('commodityCode');
                        V_QUANTITY := order_item.get_number('quantity');
                        V_UNIT_CODE := order_item.get_string('unitCode');

                        -- Insert into ITEMORDER table (replace with your actual insert statement)
                        INSERT INTO MSA_SCHEMA.ITEMORDER (ORDER_ID, RRN, STAN, NATIONAL_CODE, CARD_NUMBER, TERMINAL_NUMBER, CHANNEL_TYPE, REQUEST_DATE, AMOUNT, COMMODITY_CODE, QUANTITY, UNIT_CODE)
                        VALUES (V_ORDER_ID, V_RRN, V_STAN, V_NATIONAL_CODE, V_CARD_NUMBER, V_TERMINAL_NUMBER, V_CHANNEL_TYPE, V_REQUEST_DATE, V_AMOUNT, V_COMMODITY_CODE, V_QUANTITY, V_UNIT_CODE);
                    END IF;
                END LOOP;

                COMMIT;
            END IF;
        END IF;
        
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            RAISE;
    END PROCESS_JSON_DATA;
END PKG_ORDER;
```

Comment: i solved my problem just with change this line>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>  form: FOR i IN 0..order_items.get_size() >>>>>>to: FOR i IN 0..order_items.get_size()-1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use a single SQL statement with `JSON_TABLE` rather than trying to process the JSON in PL/SQL using loops.

Assuming the setup:

```sql
CREATE TABLE MSA_SCHEMA.ITEMORDER (
  RRN VARCHAR2(50),
  STAN VARCHAR2(50),
  NATIONAL_CODE VARCHAR2(100),
  CARD_NUMBER VARCHAR2(50),
  TERMINAL_NUMBER VARCHAR2(50),
  CHANNEL_TYPE NUMBER,
  REQUEST_DATE DATE,
  AMOUNT NUMBER,
  COMMODITY_CODE VARCHAR2(50),
  QUANTITY NUMBER,
  UNIT_CODE VARCHAR2(10),
  ORDER_ID NUMBER
)

CREATE SEQUENCE MSA_SCHEMA.ITEMORDER_SEQ;

CREATE PACKAGE MSA_SCHEMA.PKG_ORDER AS
    PROCEDURE PROCESS_JSON_DATA(P_JSON_DATA IN VARCHAR2);
END;
/
```

Then you can use:

```sql
CREATE PACKAGE BODY MSA_SCHEMA.PKG_ORDER AS
    PROCEDURE PROCESS_JSON_DATA(P_JSON_DATA IN VARCHAR2) IS
      V_ORDER_ID NUMBER;
    BEGIN
      V_ORDER_ID := MSA_SCHEMA.ITEMORDER_SEQ.NEXTVAL;

      INSERT INTO MSA_SCHEMA.ITEMORDER (
        ORDER_ID,
        RRN,
        STAN,
        NATIONAL_CODE,
        CARD_NUMBER,
        TERMINAL_NUMBER,
        CHANNEL_TYPE,
        REQUEST_DATE,
        AMOUNT,
        COMMODITY_CODE,
        QUANTITY,
        UNIT_CODE
      )
      SELECT v_order_id,
             RRN,
             STAN,
             NATIONAL_CODE,
             CARD_NUMBER,
             TERMINAL_NUMBER,
             CHANNEL_TYPE,
             TO_DATE(REQUEST_DATE, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'),
             AMOUNT,
             COMMODITY_CODE,
             QUANTITY,
             UNIT_CODE
      FROM   JSON_TABLE(
               p_json_data,
               '$'
               COLUMNS(
                 RRN             VARCHAR2(50)  PATH '$.rrn',
                 STAN            VARCHAR2(50)  PATH '$.stan',
                 NATIONAL_CODE   VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.nationalCode',
                 CARD_NUMBER     VARCHAR2(50)  PATH '$.cardNumber',
                 TERMINAL_NUMBER VARCHAR2(50)  PATH '$.terminalNumber',
                 CHANNEL_TYPE    NUMBER        PATH '$.channelType',
                 REQUEST_DATE    NUMBER        PATH '$.requestDate',
                 AMOUNT          NUMBER        PATH '$.amount',
                 NESTED PATH '$.orderItems[*]' COLUMNS (
                   COMMODITY_CODE  VARCHAR2(50)  PATH '$.commodityCode',
                   QUANTITY        NUMBER        PATH '$.quantity',
                   UNIT_CODE       VARCHAR2(10)  PATH '$.unitCode'
                 )
               )
             );
    END PROCESS_JSON_DATA;
END PKG_ORDER;
/
```

*Note: Do not `COMMIT` in procedures as it prevents you from chaining multiple procedures together and if a later one fails then you can use `ROLLBACK` to revert all the changes. Instead, `COMMIT` from the code that calls the procedure(s).*

*Note 2: Don't catch the `OTHERS` exception and `RAISE` it again without doing anything as its pointless and you can just omit that part.*

If you test it using:

```sql
BEGIN
  MSA_SCHEMA.PKG_ORDER.PROCESS_JSON_DATA(
    '{
  "rrn": "a",
  "stan": "b",
  "nationalCode": "c",
  "cardNumber": "d",
  "terminalNumber": "e",
  "channelType": 1,
  "requestDate": 19700101000000,
  "amount": 2,
  "orderItems": [
    {"commodityCode": "f", "quantity": 3, "unitCode": "g"},
    {"commodityCode": "h", "quantity": 4, "unitCode": "i"},
    {"commodityCode": "j", "quantity": 5, "unitCode": "k"}
  ]
}'
  );
END;
/
```

Then the table contains:

| RRN | STAN | NATIONAL_CODE | CARD_NUMBER | TERMINAL_NUMBER | CHANNEL_TYPE | REQUEST_DATE | AMOUNT | COMMODITY_CODE | QUANTITY | UNIT_CODE | ORDER_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c | d | e | 1 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | 2 | f | 3 | g | 1 |
| a | b | c | d | e | 1 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | 2 | h | 4 | i | 1 |
| a | b | c | d | e | 1 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | 2 | j | 5 | k | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HZQ7WV3x)